# Scala async import not working on IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, async-await

value async is not a member of scala
import scala.async.Async.{async, await}

Comment: Welcome to SO, we need more context to help you: does it work with SBT outside of IntelliJ? How does your `build.sbt` file look like? Is it in a worksheet maybe?

Answer (score 2):

Can you import anything from the `scala.async` package at all ?

The `scala.async` package is not automatically imported in Scala.
To use it, you need to add it as a dependency to your project.
This depends on the build tool you use for your project.

If you use `sbt`, you need to add this dependency to your `build.sbt`:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-async" % "1.0.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-reflect" % scalaVersion.value % Provided
```

For `maven`, you should add this in your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.scala-lang.modules</groupId>
  <artifactId>scala-async_2.13</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
  <artifactId>scala-reflect</artifactId>
  <version>2.13.8</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

You might need to check your Scala version, as per the official documentation:

> As of scala-async 1.0, Scala 2.12.12+ or 2.13.3+ are required.

Also, be sure to check if you need to to enable compiler support for `async`.

You will find everything I provided in more detail at their official [documentation](https://index.scala-lang.org/scala/scala-async). You should also check their [github](https://github.com/scala/scala-async) to see the latest release.